# jQuery Autocomplete Assistance

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

First time post so bear with me...I have been attempting to incorporate the code for jQuery Autocomplete found here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ into my project so that I can tweak it. I have been looking around for solutions for the better part of the day with no success.

I have tried simply pasting in the Autocomplete code into notepad++ and saving as an html file and pulling it up in my browser (chrome) with no success as well as trying in jsfiddle same result. I can see the text box but unfortunately when I type in anything nothing is picked up by Autocomplete.

I am not sure if it has something to do with the  tags or if I am just that inexperienced and am missing something obvious that more seasoned developers would realize quickly.

Below is my attempt to add in the referenced code from the jQuery Autocomplete page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Just for reference the first bit of my work is shown below (I know I need to add certain  tags but am unsure of which - even after adding the ones shown in the example code I am unsuccessful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Your Team</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Your first code example works fine when put in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3uz3u9e0/. When you test locally however you need to include the http protocol in the libraries (change `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"` to `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"`).

Comment: Huge help this should keep me busy for a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make sure libraries are added to the jsfiddle

I have added the link for you (note on the left side the jquery library was added)

http://jsfiddle.net/nz3Luyu8/

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Correct as soon as I made the changes you guys had to the frameworks and extensions part I was able to get it to work. Before when I changed out those extensions I must have been changing them incorrectly, so thanks again!